# nginx lua set proxy headers

Tags: nginx, proxy, lua

I believe this should be an easy find but for the life of me I cannot find an answer.  I am trying to set proxy headers and I have tried the following ways:

```
location / {
        access_by_lua '
            ngx.header["ZZZZ"] = zzzzz
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8888;
        ';
```

OR

```
location / {
        access_by_lua '
            ngx.proxy_set_header["ZZZZ"] = zzzzz
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8888;
        ';
```

What is the correct way to set a proxy header.

Thank you
stabiuti

Answer (score 7):

To set or clear headers being sent to proxy_pass, you can use following

to set headers, use

```
ngx.req.set_header(header_name, value)
```

to clear headers, use

```
ngx.req.clear_header(header)
```

to clear all headers, you can write

```
for header, _ in pairs(ngx.req.get_headers()) do
    ngx.req.clear_header(header)
end
```

Now to answer your question, you can use

```
location / {
        access_by_lua_block {
            ngx.req.set_header("ZZZZ", zzzzz)
        }
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8888;
}
```

Make sure to write it in access_by_lua or rewrite_by_lua.

Answer (score 3):

```
server{
    location /v1 {
        if ($request_method != 'OPTIONS' ) {
            header_filter_by_lua_block{
                local allowed = {["cache-control"]= true,["content-language"]=true,["content-type"]=true,["expires"]=true};
                for key,value in pairs (ngx.resp.get_headers()) do
                    if (allowed[string.lower(key)]==nil) then
                        ngx.header[key]="";
                    end
                end
            }
        }
    }
    proxy_pass https://smth:8080; 
}
```

This is my example how to change the headers sent to the client

> Note that ngx.header is not a normal Lua table and as such, it is not
>   possible to iterate through it using the Lua ipairs function.
>
> Note: HEADER and VALUE will be truncated if they contain the \r or \n
>   characters. The truncated values will contain all characters up to
>   (and excluding) the first occurrence of \r or \n.
>
> For reading request headers, use the ngx.req.get_headers function
>   instead.
>   (https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxheaderheader)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a correct way. You dont need to use lua for setting proxy headers. Without lua, you can simply do:

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header ZZZZ zzzzz;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8888;
}
```

You can read more about nginx proxy module here: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html